# how do I connect MySQL to SPSS

Tags: mysql, spss

I have a MySQL database with several gigabytes of data I want to analyse. I have installed SPSS 22 and I am trying to get it to connect to MySQL using the ODBC Data Source Administrator. It seems fine with Access, MS SQL etc, but I can't get it to connect to MySQL.

I'm using XAMPP 32bit on a Windows 7 64 bit machine. I've installed:

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/ (installing the 32bit version to match the version of MySQL)

And when I set up the connections in Win7 Administrative tools -> ODBC Data Course Administrator and I can't see any way to register a MySQL ODBC connection

Am I missing something?

EDIT:
As the OS is 64 bit it requires a 64 bit ODBC connector. Installing the 64 ODBC connector allows me to build a connection, but as the database is 32 bits we get a mismatch and it won't connect.

```
    "architecture mismatch"
```

Solution would be to install a 64 bit version of XAMPP, but they don't seem to build them

Comment: We don't know what you've tried, so we can't tell if you're missing something.

Comment: thanks, have updated the question

Comment: SPSS's bitness needs to match the database. So the installation of SPSS would need to be 32 bit as well. It is fine to install 32 bit SPSS on a 64 bit system.